# call the return value in another method

Tags: java, return-value

i want to use the value of o in another method how can i do it. i search alot but unsucessful!!!

```html
public static Object getKeyFromValue(Map hm, Object value) {
    for (Object o : hm.keySet()) {
      if (hm.get(o).equals(value)) {
          System.out.println("find "+o); // like this but when i write it on another method error occor!!!
          
        return o;
```

Comment: By passing `o` as an argument to the said method?

Comment: how i did a lot of things

Comment: We need to see an excerpt of what that other method looks like and how it is being invoked.

Comment: getKeyFromValue(col, node); like this ?? didnot work

Comment: What is the "other method"?

Comment: *like this but when i write it on another method error occor!!!* <----- What is "another method"? Copy that method and paste it into your question

Comment: Please put the code which compiles correctly. Parenthesis should match.

Comment: this method is actually find the value of key through the value of linkedhashmap,,, in return 0 in gives the key.

Comment: "_i want to use the value of o in another method_" Then call the method as an argument `someMethod(getKeyFromValue(col, node))`

Comment: this method find the key through the value which is string. now in another method i want to use that key to remove like map.put(o); but didnt work

Comment: You would use the parameter name from `someMethod`, not the local variable name from `getKeyFromValue`. And as everyone has said, post the actual example you have been trying so we can edit it for you - just saying "something I tried didn't work" does no good.

Comment: csmckelvey can u describe withe the help of code/

Comment: when i run the code which is mention in my post it return an int like 1 or 5, i want to use that particular number in another method

Comment: simple how er can pass o as an argument , my question is that

Comment: Why can't you replace `System.out.println("find "+o);` with `theMethod(o)` ?

Comment: Why don't you post the code where you want to use o? The Map you have as  1st parameter, is that java.util.Map?

Comment: let me check that way

Comment: Set set = col.entrySet();

              
                 Iterator i = set.iterator();
     while(i.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
         System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
         System.out.println(me.getValue());
        
              
      }
     
      System.out.println( (getKeyFromValue(col,TextField2.getText())));
  
             node.remove(selectednode);

Comment: node.remove(selectednode); it remove the node from jtree, then i also want to remove it from linkedhashmap. hm.put(o); o is return value.

Comment: getKeyFromValue(col, node); this one work but it gave the key as well as value of hashmap i only need key to remove like hm.put();
            getKeyFromValue(0); it gaves error;

Comment: LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> col = new LinkedHashMap<>();

Comment: now i hope u can understand

Comment: code is to lengthy cannot post in comment

Comment: by the way i am a beginner just start an internship,,

 i consume one week only for make an jtree in netbeans that take values from user and save it in LinkedHashMap.

any suggestion would be helful from you people to guide me a little in this field. i think thats too tough i consume 1 week for just a little work.
i have complex that i am too slow or everyone in the start is like me?
any helping material recommendation that make strong my programmong concepts would be helpful.
your help will be appreciated alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest searching for and removing the object at the same time rather that using two methods, btw its remove() you should use not put() for this.

Here is my way to do this, as you can see I also use Integer/String rather than Object, no point in using a superclass when you have only String values.

```
public static void removeObject(Map<Integer, String> map, String value) {
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map) {
       if (entry.getValue().equals(value) ) {
           map.remove(entry.getKey());
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks it helps. actually i am a beginner. 
by the way i am a beginner just start an internship,, i consume one week only for make an jtree in netbeans that take values from user and save it in LinkedHashMap. any suggestion would be helful from you people to guide me a little in this field. i think thats too tough i consume 1 week for just a little work. i have complex that i am too slow or everyone in the start is like me? any helping material recommendation that make strong my programmong concepts would be helpful. your help will be appreciated alot.

Comment: joakim Danielson. what should i read and from where to do strong my basic knowledge. your response means alot

Comment: If you're on an internship I assume you will get some kind of mentoring? It is always good to pick up a text book and learn the basic of java and OO programming.

Comment: No Mentoring they just give me work like make jtree and take value from user, no guidance from  their side. can you recommend any book?
Joakim can you guide me in little detail. i have complex that i am too slow for programming. may be thats because no mentoring from their side or i am just an beginner.

Comment: It was a long time since I learned myself so I don't have any good knowledge about current books but looking at Amazon I saw there was a book "Head First Java" and I remember liking another book from them that I read many years ago. It might be worth checking out.

Comment: appreciated man. what about the complex i have, is mostly people are like me in the beginning or i am the unique case? because it disturbs me a lot i cannot fully focus because of that complex as a beginner.

Comment: please one last request answer my last comment

Comment: It’s impossible for me to say, I had taken some courses at university and had good support from my employer when I started in the business. But it’s a lot to learn in the beginning, the java language itself, the jdk, design and other stuff so it will probably take some time and hard work.